# How can I blacklist a particular IP address (dos.yaml does not seem to work)

Tags: google-app-engine, blacklist

I have this dos.yaml file:

```
blacklist:
- subnet: 202.113.48.130
  description: they are doing 1000s of requests for a nonexistent file
```

I did a `appcfg.py update .` some hours ago.
The new console doesn't appear to show the blacklist at all, but the old one does and shows that the above address is blacklisted.

However, the logs right up to this minute show that requests are coming from this IP address and are receiving 404 as reply.

Is there any other step I need to take to make the blacklist work?

Or is there an alternative to stop these constant requests for a nonexistent file?

Thanks.

Comment: Well it is more than 48 hours later and either they have stopped requesting or the blacklist is finally working, I don't know which; hopefully both.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dos?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Uploading_DoS_configuration) you should use the `appcfg.py update_dos` command.

Comment: Just using update is sufficient -- it even tells you it is updating the DOS; but I did as you suggested and it still doesn't work. The address is shown blacklisted (using the old console, and as it was after I did update .), but still has no effect.

Comment: Time to contact Google support, lack of effect + config inconsistencies between consoles could indicate some issue with your app.